# ES6 syntax giving error in minification IN AEM 6.0

Tags: aem

i have used some third party ES6 library . when we are minifying client lib tons of error is coming . What should i do

Comment: what was the workaround you ended up doing for 6.0 and ES6

Comment: Since this is a vendor library, they must provide an ES5 version. Otherwise, you can just transpile it yourself with Babel or some other transpiler.  Using GCC is also an option as SubSul mentioned.

Comment: I would do all the minifying outside of AEM and just disable min on your client libs, add these attributes to your .content.xml file for your clientlib.
    jsProcessor="[default:none,min:none]"
    cssProcessor="[default:none,min:none]"

example: https://github.com/aem-design/aemdesign-aem-support/blob/clean-up-compose-project/aemdesign-aem-compose/.maven/content/jcr_root/apps/aemdesign-compose/clientlibs/core/clientlibs-footer/.content.xml

Answer (score 9):

AEM 6.0 - YUI minification engine - does NOT support ES6. You'll have to make do with using lower versions of javascript. Check out for service packs which might enable this feature in 6.0. Or if your project setup uses webpack / npm etc, then transpilers like babel can do the trick.

---

AEM 6.2 Onwards

You have an option of setting the minification engine in configuration manager  to GCC - `Google closure compiler` which supports ES6 syntax - in other words transpiles ES6+.

From [AEM docs](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/clientlibs.html#UsingPreprocessors),

> YUI is set as the default minifier in AEM. To change this to GCC,
>   follow these steps.
>
> Go to Apache Felix Config Manager at
>   http://localhost:4502/system/console/configMgr
>
> Find and edit the Adobe Granite HTML Library Manager.
>
> Enable the Minify option (if not already enabled).
>
> Set the value JS Processor Default Configs to min:gcc.
>
> Options can be passed if separated with a semicolon e.g.
>   min:gcc;obfuscate=true.
>
> Click Save to save the changes.

You have a choice of configuring the preprocessor per clientlib or system-wide:

For system-wide config, add this configuration as an HTML Library Manager OSGi run mode config, that way the build process takes care of updating this property in all the other environments (dev, stage, test, ...), saving you from  manually editing this property across everywhere.

PID: `com.adobe.granite.ui.clientlibs.impl.HtmlLibraryManagerImpl`

For clientlib specfic config, add `cssProcessor` and `jsProcessor` properties on the clientlib node
e.g:  `jsProcessor="[min:gcc;obfuscate=true;languageIn=ECMASCRIPT6;languageOut=ECMASCRIPT3]`

Refer to [Google Closure Compiler docs](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/compilation_levels) for the different available configuration options.

Comment: For future references: Today it's `languageIn=ECMASCRIPT_2015`, in case ECMASCRIPT6 doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There was one minified js  library file which was minified by some other minification engine . That minified file not supported by AEM 6.0 . So i took that file's unminified version and put it in clientlib and it is started working .

Comment: thats good to know, you might want to accept an answer for the benefit of the community, just might help others stumbling upon a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

in AEM 6.5.8, change HTML library manager: js default processor to min:gcc. For client library folder, add: jsProcessor=[min:gcc;obfuscate=true;languageIn=ECMASCRIPT_2019;languageOut=ECMASCRIPT3]. Then works.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, the minify and transcompile won't happen for this configuration, just the AEM forms rule editor can pass the validation for arrow function.